# Company requires me to use my personal cell phone to work. Writeoff?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

Question for the tax professionals.

I work from home, recently my company has implemented MFA (multi-factor authentication) on several internal sites necessary for my job.  The MFA app has to be installed on my personal phone so that each time I login to these work sites I have to enter a code that is on my phone (or press an "Ok" button on my phone to authorize the login).

Company doesn't pay for my phone or provide one for me.

Is my cellphone service something that can be written off, in whole or in part, from my income taxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not authoritative, but according to [TurboTax](http://blog.turbotax.intuit.com/tax-deductions-and-credits-2/can-i-deduct-my-mobile-phone-and-other-electronic-devices-11670/):

> If your new cell phone acts as both your business and personal phone, you are only allowed to deduct the portion used for business from your taxable income. It’s important for you to hang on to your itemized phone bill and receipts to ensure that you’re deducting the right amounts and to keep records of your deduction.

Since the usage you're describing sounds like a very small amount of the overall usage, it will probably be difficult to justify a business expense deduction.